# Cambiar pagine del iframe desde dentro del mismo

Tags: jsf, primefaces, iframe

Buenas necesito una ayudita con lo siguiente:

Tengo un proyecto donde uso una pagina para mostar un menu fijo y justo de debajo esta un iframe para mostrar las paginas que estan especificada con cada boton del menu

Form del iframe:

```
<h:form id="formVisualizador" style="height:92%">
    <iframe src="#{linkMenu.pagina}" name="option" style="height: 99%; width: 100%; min-width: 1055px; border:none; background-image: url('resources/img/filmreel1.png');" scrolling="auto"></iframe>
</h:form>
```

Como pueden ver el iframe adquiere la direccion de la pagina mediante una variable la cual se asigna en los botones del menu.

Ahora mi problema esta en que tengo que cambiar de pagina del iframe desde la pagina que muestra el iframe y el problema reside en que no puedo hacer update desde dentro de iframe ya probe usando `update=":formVisualizador"` y `update="@all"`, con el `update="@all"` no muestra error pero no cambia de pagina mientras que con el `update=":formVisualizador"` marca error de que no puede encontrar el elemento.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Podrías en la pagina que muestras en el iframe tener un iframe vacio para que cuando quieras actualizar la pagina ocultas todo y cargas la pagina en el iframe. en realidad no recargar la pagina solo ocultas todo y muestras la pagina en el iframe que esta dentro de la pagina mostrada inicialmente en el iframe.